# Raise OAB version in Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange

I'm encountering issues with a OAB that was migrated from Exchange 2003 to 2010. I've moved the OAB using `Move-OfflineAddressBook` and set the new Exchange 2010 as generation server. Nevertheless the OAB version is still 0.0. That means that I can not enable web based distribution for that OAB. I tried to upgrade the OAB using `Set-OfflineAddressBook "name of oab" -ApplyMandatoryProperties` which resulted in an error saying

> MinAdminVersion should not be empty when Exchange Version is 0.10 (14.0.100.0).

Is there any way to upgrade the OAB to support web distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, solved it by setting the msExchMinAdminVersion of the OAB using ADSIEdit. Go to `CN=Offline Address Lists, CN=Address Lists Containers, CN=YourOrganisation, CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services, CN=Configuration, DC=yourdomain, DC=com`, right click on your OAB and set the `msExchMinAdminVersion` propterty to `-536840812`.